# Windows 10 privilege/user rights/ownership issues

Tags: windows-10, administrator, ownership

I was trying to get access to `%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps`, but the OS won't let me, and while I don't remember why I needed access to it, it had something to do with an ESP8266 microcontroller board I was installing something for, so I changed ownership of it to give myself access. After doing so, a few things changed and broke:

- When logging into Windows 10, my username has changed, and my user icon is gone
- Explorer View: *Details* | Sort by: *Date Modified* 
   Saving a file in a directory doesn't update the sorting of items in that folder, with the new file now ending up at the bottom, having to manually refresh in order to see the latest files on top
- When saving some files, I have to save as Admin when I was previously able to save the files normally, including folders outside of `WindowsApps`

How can I return my system to use the correct permissions for `WindowsApps`?

Comment: Regarding Python, please consider adding the results of `where pip` and `where python` to this question.

Comment: You cannot, and should not, modify the ACLs of `%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps`, as the ACLs are configured to sandbox apps, and modifying them will always result in issues since they're not intended to be user modified _(it's analogous to modifying ACLs on subdirectories within `%WinDir%`)_. As to the user, did you set up a local user in OOBE, then convert it to a Microsoft account _(also allows the user to be any name, however this has nothing to do with ACLs)_? To fix the issue, you can try `icacls "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps" /t /q /c /reset`, but no guarantee, else perform a Repair Install.

Comment: @JW0914 The reason why I needed access is because somehow my Python install is in that folder and I needed access to some files to manually edit them in VScode. Using your command for icacls returned:
Successfully processed 29031 files; Failed processing 278 files
I will reboot and see how that panned out. Thanks for your suggestion!

Okay, rebooted, but now I get a bunch of error messages saying 'the parameter is incorrect' and it actually broke more now.. Also a few other programs don't work now. Is there a way to reverse icacls?

Comment: You need to do a repair install - download the [Windows install ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) and launch `setup.exe` while booted to Windows, choosing to keep all files & settings. As to your Python files, you'll likely want to either install [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) directly or use [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/)  [Community] _(the full IDE environment)_], which has a Python add-on, as `WindowsApps` is off-limits to user modification and this will never change because it's a safeguard to sandbox UWP Apps.

Comment: @JW0914 Thanks, let me add that the 'parameter is incorrect' messages relates to the four items that are in the startup routine. Does that change anything or do I still have to do a repair install?

Comment: A Repair Install is the only method I'm aware of to fix ACLs on system directories if the [`icacls /reset`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls) parameter fails to do so

Comment: @JW0914 Alright, I will get down to it. For the Python part I'll make a new subject. Let me clarify that I've never had problems with Python in the past 10+ years that I've been creatively coding. It only started giving trouble since this new computer. I usually create a venv and also tried PyCharm, but somehow nothing wants to work the way it should ever since I switched. I also use VScode for all my work, so it's very frustrating and I want to squash this problem once and forever. I'll let you know how the repair went.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122384/discussion-between-marinus-and-jw0914).